# Crystal Report Decimal Precision

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Following is a crystal report formula used in report. The result coming as value with two decimal positions.For example, 3.24. But the actual value consists 3 decimal points, as 3.245. I need to show 3 decimal value.
**Formula:**

```
totext(sum({SO_DELIVERY_RPRT_V.DISC_RATE})+{SO_DELIVERY_RPRT_V.DO_DISC_AMT})
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The generic way is totext({number_field}, 2), where 2 denotes number of decimals

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I guess it helps you,

```
totext((sum({SO_DELIVERY_RPRT_V.DISC_RATE})+{SO_DELIVERY_RPRT_V.DO_DISC_AMT}), 3)
```

The '3' in the above formula is what specifies the number of decimals. If you use '0', it will show no decimals.